# Searching an object tree structure

Tags: beginner, recursion, search, coffeescript

I have this recursive function that searches an object tree structure:

```
dataSearcher = (dataElement, identifierToFind) -> 
    if dataElement.identifier == identifierToFind
        return dataElement
    else
        for childDataElement in dataElement.children
            found = dataSearcher childDataElement, identifierToFind
            if found then return found
```

Which I then call thus:

```
foundDataElement = dataSearcher @options.nodeData, identifier
```

It works just fine so I am happy about that, but I am pretty new to CoffeeScript and would like feedback on the way I structured it.  The loop I used seems a bit old school, so could I have used a comprehension here instead?  Any other feedback would be great as I am still getting my head into the CoffeeScript idiom.

Please let me know if I should edit with more context code.

Comment: You could make the `for` a comprehension, but it wouldn't cut the visit short when a match was found, so while this is less "functional" it's just as good. The real test of code is this: which do you expect to be able to read six months from now?  I'd remove the 'else', but that's my Haskell training talking: you've got a guard condition at the top of your function, not an alternative, but that's how *I* read things.

Comment: side note: the functional abstraction for what you are doing is `mapDetect` (see https://gist.github.com/1222480 for a underscore implementation). In a lazy language it would be `(head . filter predicate)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer writing it like this:

```
dataSearcher = (element, identifier) -> 
  return element if element.identifier is identifier
  for child in element.children
    found = dataSearcher child, identifier
    return found if found
```

Changes:

- guard style instead of `else` (one less level of indentation)
- postfix `if` (probably a question of style)
- `is` instead of `==`
- shorter variable names

Comment: That is the sort of thing I am looking for...I am pretty clear I am still writing my coffeescript in a js idiom.  Good coaching.